# Problems with loop in R, returns NA

Tags: r

```
fact.weight <- matrix(NA,nrow(dax.p),2)

fact.ret <- matrix(NA,nrow(dax.p),2)  
fact.sd <- matrix(NA,nrow(dax.p),2)  
fact.cov <- matrix(NA,ncol(fact.weight),ncol(fact.weight))

for (row in 15:nrow(fact.weight)) {
   for (column in 1:ncol(fact.weight)) {
     fact.ret[row,column] <- mean(fact.wealth.return[row-1:row,column])  
     fact.sd[row,column] <- sd(fact.wealth.return[row-1:row,column])
  }
}
```

There is something wrong with my loop. `fact.ret` and `fact.sd` only returns `NA` values. The problem may be here somewhere

```
mean(fact.wealth.return[row-1:row,column])
sd(fact.wealth.return[row-1:row,column])
```

But I can't see the problem myself. Do anyone see the problem?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you please provide a sample of your data, what is dax.p?

Comment: Make sure that your data, i.e. `fact.wealth.return` does not contain any `NA`. For more info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15924398/subsetting-r-data-frame-with-nas-in-index-variable/15924914#15924914

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be in your subsetting of the vector, I think you want:

```
mean(fact.wealth.return[(row-1):row,column])
sd(fact.wealth.return[(row-1):row,column])
```

To see why, try:

```
row = 10    
row-1:row

[1] 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
```

and compare that with

```
row = 10
(row-1):row

[1]  9 10
```