# How does R handle filtering data frames

Tags: r, dataframe

Relatively new user to R and still trying to get my bearings on how R handles dataframes.

Specifically, I am trying to filter a data frame based on a column value.

The Python pandas equivalent would be:

```
df_temp = df.loc[df['col1']==1,'col1']
```

From my experience, this returns a Series where all values equal 1.

I'm trying to do something similar in R where I have a dataframe, I'm using the code below, however, I keep getting the full-length column returned with values of 1 and "NA"

```
temp <- RAVE_ITN_BVAS_ADVIS3[RAVE_ITN_BVAS_ADVIS3$`Sensorineural deafness`==1, 'Sensorineural deafness']
```

So my question is two-fold:

1. Is there a better way to filter data frames in R?
2. Does R simply turn all values that do not equal 1 into NA and then return the full-length column? If so, this would be frustrating as then it brings up issues with deal with NAs all the time.

Any input appreciates and let me know how I can further clarify.

Thank you all!

Comment: can you share your data with `dput()`

Comment: Try `df.loc[df[['col1']]==1,'col1']`. With double `[[`.

Comment: Thanks @Parfait, this led me to use:
temp <- RAVE_ITN_BVAS_ADVIS3[which(RAVE_ITN_BVAS_ADVIS3$`Sensorineural deafness`==1), 'Sensorineural deafness']

This returns a vector as I expect of just 1s

Answer (score 0):

You can use the package dplyr and use the function filter:

```
filter(RAVE_ITN_BVAS_ADVIS3, `Sensorineural deafness`==1)
```

Also, I recommend you to use the package data.table:

```
RAVE_ITN_BVAS_ADVIS3[`Sensorineural deafness`==1]
```

Best

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for the input, I ended up finding I believe a similar issue here (thanks to Parfait's comment)

[Subsetting R data frame results in mysterious NA rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14261619/subsetting-r-data-frame-results-in-mysterious-na-rows)

I ended up using:

```
temp <- RAVE_ITN_BVAS_ADVIS3[which(RAVE_ITN_BVAS_ADVIS3$`Sensorineural deafness`==1),
                             'Sensorineural deafness']
```

which returns:

```
 [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

The prior code without the use of which provided:

```
temp <- RAVE_ITN_BVAS_ADVIS3[RAVE_ITN_BVAS_ADVIS3$`Sensorineural deafness`==1,
                            'Sensorineural deafness']


   [1]  1  1 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
  [42] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  1 NA
  [83] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
 [124] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
 [165] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
 [206] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
 [247] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
 [288] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
 [329] NA NA NA NA NA NA  1 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
 [370] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
 [411] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
 [452] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
 [493] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
 [534] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  1  1 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
 [575] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
 [616] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
 [657] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
 [698] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
 [739] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
 [780] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
 [821] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
 [862] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
 [903] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
 [944] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  1 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  1  1 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  1 NA NA NA NA NA
 [985] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
 [ reached getOption("max.print") -- omitted 2499 entries ]
```