# differences between 'dplyr::filter' and [conditions, ]

Tags: r, dplyr

I get this reproducible example from [Working with names and expressions
in your tidy eval code - Lionel
Henry](https://resources.rstudio.com/rstudio-conf-2019/working-with-names-and-expressions-in-your-tidy-eval-code)

```r
library(tidyverse)
starwars %>% filter(height < 200, gender == "male") %>% dim()
```

```
## [1] 50 13
```

```r
starwars[(starwars$height < 200 & starwars$gender == "male"),] %>% dim()
```

```
## [1] 56 13
```

Seemingly, `filter(height < 200, gender == "male")` is not equal to
`(starwars$height < 200 & starwars$gender == "male")`.

```r
starwars2 <-
    starwars %>%
    mutate(index = row_number())
starwars2[(starwars2$height < 200 &
               starwars2$gender == "male"),] %>%
    anti_join(starwars2 %>%
                  filter(height < 200, gender == "male"), by = "index")
```

```
## # A tibble: 6 x 14
##   name  height  mass hair_color skin_color eye_color birth_year gender homeworld
##   <chr>  <int> <dbl> <chr>      <chr>      <chr>          <dbl> <chr>  <chr>    
## 1 <NA>      NA    NA <NA>       <NA>       <NA>              NA <NA>   <NA>     
## 2 <NA>      NA    NA <NA>       <NA>       <NA>              NA <NA>   <NA>     
## 3 <NA>      NA    NA <NA>       <NA>       <NA>              NA <NA>   <NA>     
## 4 <NA>      NA    NA <NA>       <NA>       <NA>              NA <NA>   <NA>     
## 5 <NA>      NA    NA <NA>       <NA>       <NA>              NA <NA>   <NA>     
## 6 <NA>      NA    NA <NA>       <NA>       <NA>              NA <NA>   <NA>     
## # ... with 5 more variables: species <chr>, films <list>, vehicles <list>,
## #   starships <list>, index <int>
```

So, `(starwars2$height < 200 & starwars2$gender == "male")` does not
deal with all NA rows? Is there any argument in `[...]` to make
`(starwars2$height < 200 & starwars2$gender == "male")` equal to
`filter(height < 200, gender == "male")`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Subsetting R data frame results in mysterious NA rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14261619/subsetting-r-data-frame-results-in-mysterious-na-rows)

Comment: As far I get it, the only solutions are using `subset(starwars, starwars$height < 200 & starwars$gender == "male")` or explicitly testing via `... & !is.na(...)`.